# Telling Clang Static Analyzer about third-party libraries owning references

Tags: cocoa, clang-static-analyzer

I maintain an Objective-C project which uses a C library that implements a garbage-collected scripting environment. In several cases, I need to put a retained Objective-C object in the private field of a scripting object. The Objective-C object is then released in a finalize callback.

The call to set the private value looks like this, with hopefully obvious semantics:

```
if (!JS_SetPrivate(context, jsSelf, [self retain])) /* handle error */
```

The finalize callback does this:

```
id object = JS_GetPrivate(context, jsSelf);
if (object != nil)
{
    [object clearJSSelf:jsSelf]; // Remove reference to JS wrapper.
    [object release];  // JS wrapper owned a reference.
    JS_SetPrivate(context, jsSelf, nil);
}
```

The Clang Static Analyzer has no objection to the random release in the finalize callback, but where the value is initially set it says “Potential leak of an object allocated on line N.”

Is there an annotation or non-ugly pattern that would suppress this message? (I’d rather not be doing silly things like `[object performSelector:@selector(retain)]`. I’d also prefer not to mess with the header declaring `JS_SetPrivate`. Also note that the value given to `JS_SetPrivate` is an arbitrary pointer, not necessarily an Objective-C object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the new NS_CONSUMED attribute on JS_SetPrivate:

http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/annotations.html#attr_ns_consumed

Comment: As per Twitter: ns_consumed does not work with `void *` pointers. This is a reasonably general issue for context pointers/refcons/“closures”. http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=9075

Comment: My “solution” – read it and weep: `static inline OOConsumeReference(id __attribute__(ns_consume) value) __attribute__((always_inline)) { return value; }`

Comment: I just get unknown attribute. Even when I force Xcode 4 to compile with “LLVM 2”.

Comment: @Max Are you using `ns_consumed`? There’s a typo in Ahruman’s comment.

Comment: For the record, my nasty solution no longer works (checker-262/263). I haven’t investigated new hackarounds yet.